# (Proof verification) Find the radius of convergence for the power series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{k^k}x^k$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Find the radius of convergence for the power series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{k^k}x^k$.

> I will try to use the Ratio Test find the radius of convergence.  Let
>   $f_k=\frac{k!}{k^k}x^k$. Then,
>
> $$\frac{f_{k+1}}{f_k} = \frac{(k+1)!x^{k+1}}{(k+1)^{k+1}}\cdot
>  \frac{k^k}{(k)!x^{k}}$$ $$\implies \frac{f_{k+1}}{f_k}= x \cdot
>  (\frac{k}{k+1})^k$$
>
> Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{n+1}{n})^n = e$. If $y_k \to L$,
>   then we know that $\frac{1}{y_k}\to\frac{1}{L}$. Letting $y_k =
>  (\frac{k}{k+1})^k$, we can see that $\frac{1}{y_k}\to e$. Hence,
>    $x\cdot(\frac{k}{k+1})^k\to\frac{x}{e}$. For any $x \in (-e,e)$,
>    $x\cdot(\frac{k}{k+1})^k\to L<1$. Hence, the radius of convergence is
>    $(-e,e)$ by the Ratio Test. $\blacksquare$

Comment: "Hence, the radius of convergence is $(-e,e)$" Hmmm... the radius of a convergence is a *number*.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have said $R=e$.

Comment: $$\frac{f^{k+1}}{f^k} = \frac{(k+1)! x^{k+1}}{(k+1)^{k+1}}\cdot\frac{k^{k}}{ k! x^{k}}$$ you have a typo there.

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you, I corrected it

Comment: @BarryCipra: sure, you are right, the radius of convergence is $e$ as stated by the OP (that clearly follows from Stirling inequality, for instance). The function related with $W$ is $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k^k}{k!} x^k$, my bad.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I figured it was an upside down misreading.  Been there, done that....